# Why are my input variable properties undefined (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, service

I'm fetching data from my service in the app component, and then passing it down to a child component via @Input.   when I console.log the data in ngOnInit, it DOES show up in the child component, but when I try to pass it to a variable and use it in the child template, it's coming back undefined, and I'm not sure why.

**Here's where I call my service in app.component.ts, the data that is having issues is this.colorcounts. Console logging here inside the ngOnInit DOES show the correct data. colorCounts has 3 properties: red, yellow & green:**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.pciService.getPciInfo()
            .subscribe((pciInfo) => {
              this.spinner.hide();
              this.pciData = pciInfo.sorted,
              this.colorCounts = pciInfo.counts;
            });
```

**Here's the app.component.html template where I'm passing the data down:**

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="colorCounts" [colorCounts] = "colorCounts"></app-navbar>
<app-system-status [pciData]="pciData"></app-system-status>
```

**Here's the child component where I'm grabbing the data, doing a console.log in ngOnInit does work, but trying to use "red" in the template or save it in the class comes back undefined:**

```
  constructor(private pciService: PciService,
              public dialog: MatDialog,
              private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) { }

  AMVersion: any;
  @Input() colorCounts: Colors;


  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AmVersionDialogComponent, {
      panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container',
      data: {}
    });

    (<AmVersionDialogComponent>dialogRef.componentInstance).AMVersion = this.AMVersion;
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.pciService.getAMVersion()
    .subscribe((AMInfo) => {
     return this.AMVersion = AMInfo;
    });
    var red = this.colorCounts.red;
    console.log(red)
    console.log(this.colorCounts);
  }

}
```

I know I'm probably missing something simple regarding the life cycle. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Sorry, the system status data is loading fine, it's the other data to which I added the ngIF  "colorCounts" that is having issues.

Comment: What are the input of your console.log(red) and console.log(this.colorCounts) ? Are they undefined ?

Comment: @Exomus No, they are actually showing the data that they should be. It's only when I try to pass them into the template that they show undefined, or defining them in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Observables are async so in template `*ngIf` condition will check variable and if it is null will return null but if You pipe variable as `| async` it will be checking this variable all time and when variable will apear not null it will show content `ngIf`.

`*ngIf` works only once !!! He not waiting for anny http calls and Observables are making one usualy. If You want to `*ngIf` wait for calls You need to use `| async` pipe inside.

Same as You subscribe to it in `ngOnInit()` and assign to variables in template. Subscription will assign those values later after template is allredy on screen.  Read about what async means.

You need to know that this is a boilercode:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.pciService.getPciInfo()
            .subscribe((pciInfo) => {
              this.spinner.hide();
              this.pciData = pciInfo.sorted,
              this.colorCounts = pciInfo.counts;
            });
```

It is better to do it like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.pciInfo$ = this.pciService.getPciInfo()
}
```

in template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="pciInfo$ | async as pciInfo">
<app-navbar [colorCounts]="picInfo.counts"></app-navbar>
</ng-container>
```

Pipe Async will subscribe for you to an Observable.

Comment: Try to change code using code below "It is better to do like this:"

Comment: You are not really answering the question. The main point is why his code is not working first, then you can propose alternatives to his code to make it cleaner. Here we still don't know why there is this behaviour

Comment: `*ngIf` works only once !!! He not waiting for anny http calls and Observables are making one usualy. If You want to `*ngIf` wait for calls You need to use `| async` pipe inside.